# Show profile in facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

in Facebook share dialogue, I want to show clickable user profile link as shown below (for regular posts, it's usually grey):

[image: Showing user link]

The url for the above image: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fedition.cnn.com%2F2016%2F04%2F29%2Fpolitics%2Fcalifornia-primary-carly-fiorina%2F) and I am testing here: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mythicangel.com%2Farchives%2F311) from Facebook open graph debugger console.

Every open graph property is present in CNN as well as in my website, infact I am solved all kinds of warning the debugger was giving me. However in my case, it doesn't show anything. Is there anything else I am missing?

First I thought it has something to do with popularity, but I noticed the same clickable profile link in some of my friends websites also (just regular business info wordpress site), therefore popularity cannot be a measure for them.

Comment: It is the `og:author` I believe

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/#properties

Comment: @WizKid: same output unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only solution I observed to work: Provide `article:author` parameter with a valid facebook username (not userid). So, this will work:

`<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/<username-here>"`